# How to create layer-list drawable for SeekBar background?

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, layer-list

I managed to create a xml drawable which looks like this and this is how it should look like:

[image: drawable]

Code for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:color="@color/black"
                android:width="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="360dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="15dp"
                android:height="15dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="246dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="114dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="114dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="246dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="360dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

then I just apply it to my SeekBar:

```
<SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style"
/>
```

But it doesn't work... I just get this:

[image: not working]

So now I try to do it programmatically cuz it might be issue with left,top,right,bottom DP's.... Here is code for that, but result is not what I am expecting....

```
int width = seekBar.getMeasuredWidth();

ShapeDrawable line = new ShapeDrawable();
line.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
line.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

ShapeDrawable bubble1 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
bubble1.setBounds(width, 1, 0, 1);
bubble1.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
bubble1.setIntrinsicHeight(25);
bubble1.setIntrinsicWidth(25);

//bubble2, bubble3, bubble4 with different colors and then:

Drawable[] layers = {line, bubble1, bubble2, bubble3, bubble4};
seekBar.setProgressDrawable(new LayerDrawable(layers));
```

[image: not working again]

Could somebody point me to right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think a layered-list will give you what you need for your drawable. 
It looks like the circles are scaling.  From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). "All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View, by default."  A VectorDrawable can give you that background without the scaling issues but they're a little harder to produce.

Comment: What do you want your seek bar to look like as it's level progresses? It's not clear what the role of your layer-list drawable is. Is it the background or does it somehow represent the progress? A diagram, even something that is hand-drawn, would be helpful.  Your current approach to the progress drawable is not correct but it is difficult to give guidance without a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think layer-list alone will get you anywhere. If you don't want to create your own custom seekbar, I'd check some custom libraries with SeekBar in name, for example:

1. https://github.com/channguyen/range-slider-view
2. https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar
3. https://github.com/alshell7/terminal-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

Please try this open source GitHub repository, which is provided solution which is you want,

[Timeline-View](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View)

You get the result look like below,

**Screenshot:**

[image]

And one more thing about this library, you can be able to **modifying  circle  color, style, shape.**